# Why would the neutral current be significantly greater than phase current?

Tags: wiring

I am in India. The typical domestic supply here is 240v @ 50Hz 1phase.

The utility company recently replaced the old analog wheel type meter with a modern electronic meter capable of providing several readouts. Amongst these are `Ip` and `In`, which I assume are the phase current and neutral current, respectively.

I was under the impression current flowing out of the neutral is equal to the current drawn in by the device on the phase. Yet the readouts  differ by fair numbers as much as 200% as far as my attempts to test go; could be more if I try with other devices powered.

Why would the neutral current be significantly greater than phase current?

Comment: Ip and In might as well also mean peak current and, say, nominal current or something. Please post the model of the smart meter in question (or try googling it to see if your can find some docs). At least in Europe, the "phase" wire is actually referred to as "L" for "line", so "Ip" would be somewhat odd.

Answer (score 4):

On a single-phase, Euro-style connection, neutral and line must be equal - if they were not, your RCD would trip, because looking for unequal line and neutral *is how it detects ground faults*.

If neutral is larger than line, then my only guess is one or more of your neighbors has a broken neutral wire, and their neutral is returning via their neutral-earth bond, their earthing rods, the earth, to your earthing rod via your N-E bond, to your neutral.  We see that in the US from time to time.

Check with the power company, and make sure you’re not *paying for that*.  If they bill you for Line current only, that’s fine, but if their bill is based on the average of L and N, then you’re buying your neighbors’ power.

Answer (score 2):

Neutral currents should not be more than the phase currents. They could be in some individual household circuits if you've got some multi wired branch circuits on the same phase, if you even utilize them.
I would verify with the power company what In and Ip  actually are and what the units of measurement are. The smart meters I'm familiar with do not measure neutral currents.

Answer (score 2):

The neutral should be equal to or less than the phase currents. If all loads are line to neutral then the maximum neutral would be equal to the phase, however when using split phase 120v to ground or 240 leg to leg any devices that do not use a neutral would have no neutral currents. So your maximum neutral current will always be equal or less than the addition of the legs.

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to India, as specified in the question.  (Nor anywhere else using 1-phase domestic power, which I think is pretty much everywhere except North America.)

Comment: If 240 to ground single or 3 phase the answer is still the same the only differences are the wire colors kirchhoff’s law is the constant here and single , split or 3 phase all work the same with regard to power in has to return to the source.